# Adding data to a Django model associated with a user field

Tags: django

I am creating an application that contains the model `UserDetail`. In this model, there are 3 fields, a field for donations, points, and a field for the user who is associated with these points. I show these fields in the `dashboard.html` file, and everything works. My problem is that I manually have to go into `/admin` and give a user in the database a points and donations field. I want my program to automatically populate the user, donations, and points data to the database when their account is completed, giving the points and donation field a value of 0 and associating it with the user. Below is my code for both the `dashboard.html` view, which allows the data to be shown on the dashboard page, my `UserDetail` model, and the view for when the account is created. Thank you to everyone who helps!

---

**Model:**

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
  donations = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
  points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True,)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

---

**Dashboard view:**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    # assuming there is exactly one
    # this will break if there are multiple or if there are zero
    # You can (And should) add your own checks on how many userdetails objects you have for the user
    # consider using a OneToOneField instead of a ForeignKey
    user_details = UserDetail.objects.get(user=user)  # or userdetails.objects.get(user=user)
    context = {
        "donations": user_details.donations,
        "points": user_details.points,
    }
    return render(request,'dashboard.html', context=context)
```

---

**Signup View:**

```
def register(request, ):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else: 
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully created, {username} ')
                return redirect('loginpage')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "register.html",  context )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `UserDetail` object in the register view with:

```
def register(request, ):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else: 
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                UserDetail.objects.create(
                    donations=0,
                    points=0,
                    user=user
                )
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Your account has been successfully created, {username} ')
                return redirect('loginpage')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "register.html",  context )
```

For the existing records that will not be the case, so you will need to create `UserDetail`s manually for these user objects.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought it would be so easy!

Comment: I can accept the answer in 8 minutes, I will do so then